# A java console program that converts decimal to binary without using a predefined method (for)

Tags: java, for-loop, binary, console

```
public static void main(String [] args){
 byte bin[] = new byte[255];
 int a;

 System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
 System.in.read(bin);
 Integer val= Integer.parseInt(new String(bin).trim());

 for(a=1; val >= 0;a++){
   bin[a] = val%2;
   val = val/2;
 }
 System.out.println("Binary: ");
 for(int i = a-1;i >= 0;i--){
   System.out.print(bin[i]);
 }
```

Hi! this is my first question. I explored a bit about java, which I became recently interested in. I'm quite a beginner in java, honestly!

Using for, this is the solution I derived from other sources, but the problem here is the error, I've been thinking high and low, still I can't remove the "Error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte" from line[12] including the class declaration and the end class "}". oh! and I am using DrJava.

Is there something wrong with this program?

Comment: you should do casting: `bin[a] = (byte) (val % 2);`

Comment: [Java data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) use 8 bits for a byte and 32 bits for an integer.

Comment: It is not possible to convert `byte` from `int`. Compiler will give an error. @DimaSan

Comment: @SanketMakani of course it's possible.

Comment: Try it on your system! @DimaSan

Comment: @SanketMakani just a simplest example: `int a = 100; System.out.println((byte) a);` output will be: `100`.

Comment: I really don't know, it's a good thing that there're experts around!! >w<

Comment: It will give correct output till value of a is 255. After it it won't give correct output. @DimaSan

Comment: @SanketMakani not the 255 but 127, because the range of `byte` is -128 to 127 in Java, and overflowing is another question. But when the compiler will give an error as you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying `bin[a] = val%2;` where `val` **Integer** type and `bin[a]` is **byte** type. *byte is 8 bit* where *Integer is 32 bit*. You are trying to enter a 32 bit value on 8 bit memory. That's why it it giving incompatible type error.

There are some issues in your code. After fixing them it works:

```
 byte bin[] = new byte[255];
 int a;

 System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
 System.in.read(bin);
 Integer val= Integer.parseInt(new String(bin).trim());

  Integer temp = val; // keep val intact if you want to print it later    

  // Not temp >= 0, it'll run infinite. Also a=0, because later you are printing upto 0
  for (a = 0; temp > 0; a++) { 
      // temp % 2 returns int which doesn't support byte casting
      bin[a] = new Integer(temp % 2).byteValue();
      temp = temp / 2;
  }

  // print binary number
  System.out.print("Binary of " + val + " is = ");
  for (int i = a - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      System.out.print(bin[i]);
  }
```

Comment: I did see the problem after running it, it says array index out of bounds :( after adding "throws exception{" and using "bin[a] = (byte) (val % 2);" I'll try your code sir :)

Comment: It gives "array index out of bounds" in your code because of `val >= 0`. The first loop never ends and the memory of array exceeds. It should be `val >0`

Comment: Er, what?  `new Integer(temp % 2).byteValue();` why would you possibly do this instead of `(byte) (temp % 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code but I have corrected it and also added comments for more information about changes and this code also works. Try It!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Binary
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try                                 //Catching the Exception thrown by program is necessary when you use System.in.read(byte[]) so we have used it.
        {
            byte bin[] = new byte[255];
            int a;

            System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
            System.in.read(bin);            //Input will be converted to byte and stored in the byte array 'bin'.
            Integer val= Integer.parseInt(new String(bin).trim());  //Then you're converting it to Integer.
            int Original_val=val;           //Storing the value of 'val' into another variable as it will be changed in the loop so for showing output(if you want to print it) it is required.

            int Bits[]=new int[255];        //Creating integer array where the output(bits 0 or 1 as per calculation) will be stored
            for(a=1; val > 0;a++)           //Here you have written val >=0 which will  make the loop into infinite loop so change it to val > 0.
            {                               
               Bits[a] = val%2;             //Storing the output (Here Answer will be stored from array index '1' as we have started loop from 1.
               val = val/2;
            }

            System.out.println("Binary of "+ Original_val + " is ");        //Here we have used original value because after calculation value of 'val' will be changed.
            for(int i = a-1;i > 0;i--)      //Starting index for storing input is 1 in the loop for the calculation so we will print array till Array index '1'
            {
                System.out.print(Bits[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error:    "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is very interesting when you explore more and more!

Comment: Hehe I am not a sir , I am just a student pursuing B.Tech. in Information Technology.